# How to return the value of a Threading.Task(Of Boolean)

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous, task

I would like to run a task inside a method and return the value that the Task produces, how I can do it?

This is what I'm trying:

```
Private function blahblahblah as boolean

    Return Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(Of Boolean)(
        Function() As Boolean
            For X As Integer = 0 To RetryInterval
                NetworkAvaliable(String.Format(NoWebsiteRetryMessage, RetryInterval - X), True, StatusControl)
            Next
            Return False
        End Function)

End Function
```

---

It is important to clarify that I want to do it without creating other variables outside the method like for example something like this:

```
dim value as boolean

Private function blahblahblah as boolean

    Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(Of Boolean)(
        Function() As Boolean
            For X As Integer = 0 To RetryInterval
                NetworkAvaliable(String.Format(NoWebsiteRetryMessage, RetryInterval - X), True, StatusControl)
            Next
            value = False
        End Function)

     Return value

End Function
```

I want to avoid things like that.

Comment: Well you're *starting* a task - but you won't know the result that the task produces until it's finished, will you? That's the whole point of starting a task. You really need to think about when your method is going to return, vs when your task will complete.

Comment: I wondered that the Return statement will wait for the "object" to be returned... for example when you return a String.Split, first the string is splitted then after splitted is returned... really if that is a reason for a downvote ...well.

Comment: Yes, but `TaskFactory.StartNew` spins up a new task. That's the point of it. If you didn't want the code to run separately, why would you use a new task at all? I think you need to think carefully about the nature of tasks and what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: I will run the task to don't block the ui thread

Comment: Well then why would you want to wait until the task completes before returning? That's still going to block the UI thread. You need to think about this more carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Async / Await

```
Private Async Sub callBlahBlahBlah()
    Dim result = Await blahblahblah()
End Sub

Private Function blahblahblah() As Task(Of Boolean)
    Return Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(Of Boolean)(
        Function() As Boolean
            For X As Integer = 0 To RetryInterval
                NetworkAvaliable(String.Format(NoWebsiteRetryMessage, RetryInterval - X), True, StatusControl)
            Next
            Return False
        End Function)
End Function
```